# How to show bottom side bar in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio

I dont know how but I hide my blue bottom sidebar (B) in `Visual Studio Code`. But i really need this. Any help is there some shortcut to show this sidebar?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View -> Appearance -> Show Status bar

Comment: OOO thank you. I couldnt find in documentation where it is :)

Comment: [Please follow this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface)